# ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol

Tags: boot, drivers, bios, acpi, bug-reporting

So, I've just bought myself a fresh new computer and yeah, it's not exactly a well-known brand, but it is what it is.
After literally one day of using it exclusively to binge-watch Breaking Bad and commenting weird stuff in YouTube comments, I have now got this error:

`[ 39.676832] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [^^^^PC000.PEG1.PEGP], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)`

`[ 39.678746] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PICO.SBRG.ECO._Q83 due to previous error AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psparse-529)`

Sometimes it comes after a giant wall of text: https://i.imgur.com/7CPVj6q.jpg
Other times it's just these two strings. But they are always there, 100%.

I can't use my computer. The system won't load beyond this point, no matter how much time passes. I have to manually turn off the computer.

The system does **load** if I choose the Security Boot option enabled in BIOS (yeah, F2 for BIOS opens it up), but in secure boot it doesn't allow me to use WiFi, making that boot option more or less pointless for myself.

I'm not exactly sure what am I supposed to do here. Some solutions I've found on different forums suggested everything's fine, others suggested I've got a motherboard issue and I should put out a fair wad of cash for some new hardware, which instills a wee bit of anxiety from time to time.

I have had this issue for the past 3 days.

Some of my specs are:

- AMD Ryzen 7 5800H with Radeon Graphics;
- NVidia GeForce RTX 3070;
- I have had Ubuntu 20.04 installed when I first set up the computer.

I can update my specs list at any time.

There was one thing I had done — I chose some different NVidia driver from the one that was there initially, because my laptop wouldn't wake up from sleep mode. It worked like a charm, and for one day I was happy.

I haven't found this particular string with _SB.PCIO.SBRG.ECO._Q83 anywhere, I don't know what AE_NOT_FOUND means, I don't know what I've done wrong, and I am not really good with computers. That's why I'm posting this.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? ACPI errors like that are usually because the hardware is newer so using the latest and newest version of Ubuntu with the newest kernel will sometimes solve the issue.

Comment: The acpi errors are not a problem. we all have those.  If a system hangs during boot it is the process next (and that one is NOT shown on screen) that is the issue. From my exp. that always is the gpu driver. Try booting WITHOUT the 3rd party nvidia driver.

Comment: I did find some stuff about your [specific error](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=378788), except their system works fine although others have reported that the error spams their logs and basically locks the system up.

Comment: Playing a little with different NVidia drivers let me at one point use Secure Boot along with WiFi connection. I don't know how long-term is this solution, but it's a fine short-term for now, so, thanks